# Finding a conic through four given points that maximizes the area of an inscribed rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes

Tags: geometry

I would like to find the equation of the line highlighted in yellow. I was given points $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$.

I want to maximize the area of the red box to find the value of $(x, y)$. Then with the $5$ points, I can fit a conic and hopefully find the equation. I need help with using this method to solve the equation.

[image: My Diagram]

Figure From: [Equation for a distorted circular shape](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497841/equation-for-a-distorted-circular-shape/3498423#3498423)

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the equation of a conic through $A,B,C,D$ such that it has an inscribed rectangle with sides parallel to the axes of maximum area. Is that correct?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Does the conic have to be an ellipse? One might expect a hyperbola to allow a bigger rectangle. Hmm. Or maybe not!

Comment: It does not have to be an ellipse, since it may not be symmetrical.

Comment: Note: A rectangle inscribed in an ellipse (or any conic) has sides parallel to the axes of that ellipse. Consequently, you seek an "unrotated" ellipse through $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading the situation, you should have cited https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3498423/35416 as the source of that figure and given credit to its author [Narasimham](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/95860/narasimham).

Comment: All conics are symmetrical.

Answer (score 0):

In outline, we have:

(I) The fact that the conic has four points forming a rectangle with sides parallel to the axes implies that the axes of the conic must also be parallel to the axes.

(II) The configuration of the points $A,B,C,D$ and (I) together imply that the conic is an ellipse.

(III) Given (I) and (II) finding the equation of the ellipse and the maximal rectangle is straightforward.

Detail.

(I). Translate the origin so that the points $A,B$ are equal distances from the $y$-axis, and the points $C,D$ are equal distances from the $x$-axis.

With the new coordinate system, take the four vertices of the rectangle as $(\pm X,\pm Y)$ and let the equation of the conic be $f(x,y)=0$, where $$f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$

Since the vertices of the rectangle lie on the conic we have:\ 
$f(X,Y)=0\quad(1)\\
f(X,-Y)=0\quad(2)\\
f(-X,Y)=0\quad(3)\\
f(-X,-Y)=0\quad(4)$

Now (1)-(2)-(3)+(4) gives $b=0$. Then (1)-(2) gives $e=0$. Then (2)-(3) gives $d=0$. So the equation becomes $$ax^2+cy^2+f=0$$ which establishes (I).

(II). The form of the equation shows that the conic is an ellipse or a hyperbola. If it is a hyperbola, then its two axes are lines through the (new) origin at equal inclination to the horizontal. They divide the plane into four parts, but the entire curve is contained in just two of those parts, whereas there is one of $A,B,C,D$ in each part. So the conic cannot be a hyperbola. So $a,b$ must have the same sign. We know the ellipse has at least four points, so $f$ must have the opposite sign (and be non-zero), so we can take the equation to be $$ax^2+by^2=1$$ where $a,b>0$.

(III) If its vertices are $(\pm X,\pm Y)$, the area of the ellipse is $4XY$ so we wish to maximise $XY$ or equivalently $(aX^2)(bY^2)$. But $aX^2+bY^2=1$, so the product is maximised by taking $aX^2=bY^2$ (eg AM-GM theorem). Hence $X=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}},Y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2b}}$ and the area $4XY=\frac{2}{\sqrt{ab}}$.

Comment: Isn't it true, that after translation the coordinate of points $A,B,C,D$ should be $(\pm x_0, y_1)$, $(x_1, \pm y_0)$, since the origin isn't at the intersection of $AB$ and $CD$?

Comment: @VasilyMitch Thanks. Yes, I was careless there. I hope I have fixed it!